# alloc_contig_range test_pages_isolated failed

Tags: memory, dmesg

On an embedded linux system (arm cortex a9 imx.6), the hmi program froze at a certain time. At the same time there was the following log in /var/log/messages es well with "dmesg":
 alloc_contig_range test_pages_isolated(3c080, 3c094) failed

This message appears approximately once per hour. But currently 370 MB from 1024 MB are free. On this system, there is an apache webserver, php and postgresql running.

What does  alloc_contig_range exactly do? Is the memory depleted from time to time?